# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ForwardRef(Grid)`

Tags: reactjs

This is just one example of the issue, I am able to create the issue using many elements. When replacing child components of a element what is the correct approach so as not to get Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ForwardRef?

```
const dynamicJSX = () => {
  return (
    <div>Working</div>
  )
}

return (
  <Grid container >
    <Grid item >
      {dynamicJSX}
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
)
```

Comment: as @aquinq pointed out. `dynamicJSX` is not a valid jsx element or not list of jsx element. Its a component. hence it has to be rendered as `<dynamicJSX />`

Comment: `const JsxElement = <div> hey </div>`                                          
`const Component  = (props) =>  { return (<div> lol </div>) } `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `<dynamicJSX />` instead of passing its reference. This way, you probably want to rename it to `<DynamicJSX />` (for convention).

You can also call `{dynamicJSX()}` if `dynamicJSX` has more a role of util rendering method rather than a functional component.

Comment: Amazing.. I clearly missed a fundamental piece of information in my learning. Thanks!

Comment: @aquinq can you explain why these changes need to be made?

Comment: Can I ask you to take a look at my closely related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72493824/how-to-add-array-of-img-to-jsx-returned-by-react-component