# How to preload images in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have an array of images, e.g.

```
var imgsArray = [];
imgsArray[0] = new Image();
imgsArray[0].src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Queen_Elizabeth_II_in_March_2015.jpg";
imgsArray[1] = new Image();
imgsArray[1].src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Queen_Elizabeth_II_in_March_2015.jpg";
```

I would like to add the images in this array to the JSX returned by a React component. How do I do this?

I tried the following:

```
<ImageList cols={1}>
  {imgsArray.map((img) => (
    <ImageListItem key={img.src}>
      img
    </ImageListItem>
</ImageList>
```

But no images appeared, nor did any errors appear.

I also tried placing curly braces around `img` i.e. `{img}` and received the error:

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLImageElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Use JSX to declare your images instead of instantiating image elements.

Comment: What does that mean? Can you provide an example?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Camilo , I just edited to add code showing what I tried and what the outcome was.

Comment: Could you share what the ImageListItem looks like? and Would you also share how the image array is getting passed to the list component?  Have you tried to add the `key` prop to the list item?

Comment: I just tried adding curly braces around `{img}` and received the error: `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLImageElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead`

Comment: @Ángel will do! Just one sec

Comment: @Ángel , both `ImageList` and `ImageListItem` are imports from MUI https://mui.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instantiating the element and setting the `src` property is enough to start preloading the image, there is no need to attach it to the DOM.

```
const images = ['someImageUrl.jpg', 'someOtherImageUrl.jpg'];

for (const image of images) {
  const imageElement = new Image();
  imageElement.src = image;
}

<ImageList>
  {images.map((img) => (
    <ImageListItem key={img}>
      <img src={img} />
    </ImageListItem>
  ))}
</ImageList>
```

Comment: I'm manually instantiating the image elements as a solution to another problem

Comment: To explain why, I have a problem where React apparently only download images once added to JSX and then starts to render them, but if the images are large, they don't download in time and instead slowly appear top to bottom.

Comment: Updated answer, hopefully it would guide you to a solution.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. `images` is an array of strings. Are the imageElements are being used at all? It looks to me like the for loop won't have any effect.

Comment: Instantiating the image element is enough to start preloading the image, there is no need to attach it to the DOM.

Comment: In Chrome Dev Tools I'm seeing a second request to the server for the preloaded resources. The downloading phase of the second request takes way less time I would assume because the image is cached but for some reason the browser is waiting for a response from the server before it renders the image, probably to see if the resource has changes... How would we avoid this second request?

Comment: Oddly enough, I had the above problem when I was running the `for` loop at the top of my .jsx file outside of React components, but now when I run it in `useEffect()` I don't see that second request/delay.